# how to set value to input textbox jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table with a text box column and I want to get the old value and set it to the text box `onchange`.

```
        <span class="txt_b">
            <input type="number" name="" value="<?php echo $req; ?>" onchange="onChangeTest(this)" onchange="setoldvalue(this)" oldvalue="" class="input_md radious_all innershadow padding_control" id ="tk" style="width:60px;" id="qty_req_<?php echo $i; ?>" onblur="editBucket('<?php echo $row_id; ?>','<?php echo $item['Item']['code']; ?>',$('#qty_war_<?php echo $i; ?>').val(),this.value,'<?php echo $date; ?>',$('#stock_notes_<?php echo $i; ?>').val(),'<?php echo $item['Item']['pack_size']; ?>')"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="product" id="qty_reqty_" class="product" value="qty_reqty_<?php echo $i; ?>" />
</div>
<script> 
    function getoldvalue()
        {
            $('input').on('focusin', function(){
                console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
                $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
            });

            $('input').on('change', function(){
                var prev = $(this).data('val');
                $('input').val(prev);
                console.log(s);
                var current = $(this).val();
                console.log("Prev value " + prev);
                console.log("New value " + current);
            });
```

I am struggling with setting the value to the text box. How to it by `id`?

this is my jquery dialogbox

function editCart(id,code,stock_wh,stock_rq,date,notes,pack){

```
if((stock_rq%pack) != 0){

    $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
  .html('<div id="dialog"><h3>The quantity should be multiple of pack size, do you wish to continue with the quantity entered?</h3></div>')
    .dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: 'message',
    zIndex: 10000,
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 'auto',
    resizable: true,
    buttons: {

    Yes: function () {
            doFunctionForYes();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },

     No: function () {
            doFunctionForNo();

            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },

    close: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
$('#msg').hide();

function doFunctionForYes() {

   $('#msg').show();

}
function doFunctionForNo() {
alert("doFunctionForNo");

     });

} 

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$(this).val(prev)` do it? Your current `$('input').val(prev)` sets the value of *all* input elements. I don't really understand what you're trying to do though - are you saying that after the user changes the value you want to immediately set it back to its previous value?

Comment: $('input').val(prev) will change  all the textboxes in the column

Comment: Yes, that's what I already said.

Comment: yes i want to immediately change it back to the previous value nnnnnn

Comment: Isn't that what the `readonly` attribute is for? Anyway, try `$(this).val(prev)` as per my original comment.

Comment: it does change immediately..but i have a jquery dialogbox i want to change it when user click no button

Answer (score 0):

you have some issue on defining html:

1. can not have 2 id attribute for one input
2. can not have 2 onchange on input
3. oldvalue is not standard attribute

you can set data-oldvalue attribute to your input and access that with jQuery

```
<input type="text" id="qty_req_<?php echo $i; ?>" data-oldvalue="<?php echo $req; ?>" />

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     oldvalue = $("#qty_req_<?php echo $i; ?>").data('oldvalue');
});
</script>
```

the jquery code is for sample and you can use from this code everywhere which you need

Comment: in console.log() it gives me a null value

Answer (score 0):

First of you can use `$(this).data` while saving value, only if you are having `html5`. So I've just added it as `$(this).attr('data-val')`. Now the problem was, you were always having old value as `value` for `input` even though you enter anything new, and you were getting `current value` after you changed the `input value` to old `value`. There was also an `undefined` error when you logged `console.log(s)`, since `s` was not defined anywhere.

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
  $('body').append("<br/>Saving value " + $(this).val());
  $(this).attr('data-val', $(this).val());
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
  var prev = $(this).data('val');
  var current = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(prev);
  console.log("Prev value " + prev);
  console.log("New value " + current);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="txt_b">
     <input type="number" name="" value="20" class="input_md radious_all innershadow padding_control" id ="tk" style="width:60px;" id="qty_req_<?php echo $i; ?>"/>
  </span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="product" id="qty_reqty_" class="product" value="qty_reqty_<?php echo $i; ?>" />
```

Comment: this part doesnt work   $(this).attr('data-val', $(this).val());

Comment: It works, did you inspect the `DOM` element.. Run the snippet above and you will see it..

Comment: it never changes to the old value?

Comment: so on blur it has to change to old value?

Comment: i want to set the previous value to the textbox when jquery dialogbox click no

Comment: where is that `jquery dialogbox`. The answer will not help until you give complete requirement..

Comment: i just added the jquery dialogbox